# Django Url, Slug for Detail Page

Tags: django, slug, urlconf

I'm having trouble configuring my url to display a detail view. Clicking on this link: `<a href='{% url blog_detail blog.slug %}'>{{ blog.name }}</a>` shows `blog.html`, when I thought it would show `blog-detail.html`. There are no errors and the browser bar says: `example.com/blog/the-slug`, yet still displays the html from `blog.html`, not `blog-detail.html`. Any ideas why? Thanks for your ideas.

url:

```
url(r'^blog/', 'myapp.views.blog', name='blog'),
url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'myapp.views.blog_detail', name='blog_detail'),
```

views:

```
def blog(request):
    blog_list = Blog.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'blog_list':blog_list})

def blog_detail(request, slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog-detail.html', {'blog':blog})
```

---

EDIT: output requested by @omouse

This is the output from clicking on the link. It is exactly the same as `blog.html`, but it should be `blog-detail.html`.

```
<div id='content-wrapper'>
<section>
<div class='blog-name'><h2><a href='/blog/test/'>Test</a></h2></div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a ...

<div class='blog-name'><h2><a href='/blog/second-test/'>Second Test</a></h2></div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a ...
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: try this one <a href='{% url blog_detail slug=blog.slug %}'>{{ blog.name }}</a>

Comment: Yes already tried that thanks. Still no luck. Not sure what could be the issue...

Comment: can you add what the template output is?

Comment: Thanks @omouse: the template output is `blog.html`. It is simply dummy text, but I have included it above.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The urls are the problem, the first one will match everything (`/blog/`, `/blog/test/`, `/blog/awdlawdjaawld`), you need the dollar sign `$` at the end of it to *only* match `/blog/`.

```
url(r'^blog/$', 'myapp.views.blog', name='blog'),
url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'myapp.views.blog_detail', name='blog_detail'),
```

The above should work correctly.

[This is a good reference for Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rudolf absolutely right

The `/$` stopped blog from catching all the subpages which called by slug 
so if you have subpages you need to add `/$` to folder level as follow:

```
re_path('brands/$', AllBrands.as_view(), name="brands"),
re_path(r'^brands/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', BrandDetail.as_view(), name = 'brandetail'),
```

This is django 2.2

Without `/$` after brands, the slug page was showing the brands listing page.