# How do you create links using slugfield in Django generic listview class?

Tags: python, django, html, django-models, django-class-based-views

How to you create links (i.e. href) using SlugField for the output of Django's ListView generic class? Right now I can list all persons in the database using the code below but I want links using slug when clicked will show the person's description.

```
models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

views.py
class PersonList(ListView):
    model = Person 

person_list.html
<ul>
{% for person in object_list %}
    <li>{{ person.first_name }}&nbsp{{ person.last_name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080083/django-url-slug-for-detail-page

Comment: @hansTheFranz the question is specific to generic views.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do anything in the list view. You need to add the URL to urls.py and make a detail view for your person. Then in the template reference the url and pass the slug:

`app/urls.py`:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ... other urls
    url(
        r'^person/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)$',  # Match this
        views.PersonDetailView.as_view(),  # Call this view
        name='person_detail'  # Name to use in template
   )
]
```

`app/views.py`:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Person

class PersonDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Person
```

`app/templates/app/person_list.html`:

```
<ul>
    {% for person in object_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'person_detail' slug=person.slug %}">{{ person.first_name }}&nbsp{{ person.last_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

See why this works [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) (look for slug).

Comment: Thanks for clear answer! What about doing it in listview? could you please add it as well?