# Reversing a url with two slugs

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to understand a basic example of adding both categories and detail slugs from 2 related classes.

The `/categories` URL works, but I can't make `/categories/detail` work. I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'categorydetail' with arguments '('onedetailfromcategory',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<cat_slug>[^/]+)/(?P<det_slug>[^/]+)$']
```

Here are my files:

```
#Models:

class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    cat_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Details(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    det_slug= models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name="Categories")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


#Views:         
class ListCategorie(DetailView):
    model = Categories
    slug_field = 'cat_slug'
    context_object_name = "listcategories"
    template_name = "show/categories.html"

class DetailCategorie(DetailView):
    model = Details
    slug_field = 'det_slug'
    context_object_name = "categorydetail"
    template_name = "show/detail.html"

#Urls:
    path('<cat_slug>', views.ListCategorie.as_view(), name='listcategories'),
    path('<cat_slug>/<det_slug>', views.DetailCategorie.as_view(), name='categorydetail'),

#Categories.html

{% for x in listcategories.Categories.all %}
<p> {{x.title}} </p>
<li><a href="{% url 'categorydetail' x.det_slug %}">URL</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080083/django-url-slug-for-detail-page ?

Comment: "is not working" is a totally useless description of a problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: Using `related_name="Categories"` is very confusing. You use it to get the related details for a category, therefore `related_name='details'` and `{% for detail in listcategories.details.all %}` would be much clearer.

Comment: Note that the recommendation in Django is to use singular for model names, e.g. `Categorie` and `Detail` instead of `Categories` and `Details`. I would also use `slug` instead of `cat_slug` and `det_slug`. Your code will usually be something like `categorie.slug` or `detail.slug`, so it's clear what sort of slug it is without the prefix in the fieldname.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you for detailing the good practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL pattern is

```
path('<cat_slug>/<det_slug>', views.DetailCategorie.as_view(), name='categorydetail'),
```

Therefore you need to provide `cat_slug` and `det_slug` when reversing the URL:

```
{% url 'categorydetail' x.categorie.cat_slug x.det_slug %}
```